# Regarding sending passport to CVAC from (FEDEX)

Tags: visas, canada, applications

I read on one of the websites that prepaid return envelopes from ups or usps are only accepted and other companies(Fedex) are not accepted for returning!!.Since I paid the amount and the labels i got are from FEDEX, how and what shall I do for the next process.I havent sent my documents yet. If VAC does not accept FEDEX envelopes while returning back to me then on what basis should I be sending the documents from FEDEX. Is there any other way for it.

Comment: TT Services (the corporate operator of CVAC in the US) has telephone, email, and chat contact methods available on its Contacts page: https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/contact_us.html. Have you asked them?

Answer (score 3):

The Visa Application Centres in New York and Los Angeles do not accept prepaid FedEx shipping labels for *returning your documents to you*. You can use any other service, though, [according to their web site](https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/how_to_apply.html). Or you can simply opt to pay VFS directly for return shipping.

> *NOTE: The Visa Application Centres in New York and Los Angeles no longer accept pre-paid shipping labels from FedEx. You are free to provide a shipping label envelope from any other courier company of your choice or purchase it from the Canada visa application Center

You of course can use any courier service you wish to *send your documents to the VAC*.

You also can deliver and pick up the documents in person, or have an agent do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Their website is terrible and hard to find details on sending passport to Canada Visa Center. Due to covid, They only accepts Fedex two way courier bought it online from https://visa.vfsglobal.com/usa/en/can/additional-services. Print label includes checklist with info on other required documents, including package transmission fee.